# How to filter results by app Id while using Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Google Analytics Data API (GA4) to fetch metrics from Firebase Analytics. Now I want to filter my metrics by app (website 1 or website 2 or iOS), something like what we are presented in the Project Overview section in Firebase, I can filter by the app using the visibility icon.[image]

**What is the dimension that I need to use to achieve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [streamName](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#:%7E:text=app%20or%20website.-,streamname,-Stream%20name) is the dimension that can be useful in this case.

Comment: Thank you, for pointing in the right direction, [streamId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#:~:text=upcoming%20feature%20launch.-,streamId,-Stream%20ID) is another dimension that was useful to me.